# Diffrence in Java Date and Joda Date time

Tags: java, apache-pig, jodatime

I have one date in millisecond -6847824600000.This is the input data used in pig and getting converted by using ToDate() function which internally use Joda date time to calculate the date.

The output format is like hour minitue second - 00:23:28.(Actual)
But in java Date it is giving 00:00:00 which is (Expected) output.

The local time zone is Asia/Calcutta.I have also tried with Etc/GMT+0 time zone.
Its not giving same result as java date.
I have never used Joda date time.
Please help how to get the similar output of Java date .

Comment: What exactly does the number `6847824600000` mean? Is that a count from epoch? If so, what epoch? And what granularity (seconds, milliseconds or such)? Did you mean that hyphen as a negative sign? Is this a date-time but you only give us a time-of-day? How do expect to explain the conversion when you do not post the code for this mysterious `toDate` method?

Comment: it is a negative epoch time.the time is 1753-01-01:00:00:00.To date is a built in function in apache pig.

Answer (score 1):

You have stumbled on an interesting oddity.

Seems that when a time zone is applied to this date-time of the year 1752 the [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) is mysteriously altered by 7 minutes and 2 seconds under either [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) or [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/).

> Instead of an offset of `-08:00` we see `-07:52:58`.

The old java.util.Date class shows no such surprise.

I do not have a solution or explanation. But I can demonstrate the mystery.

### Time Zone `America/Los_Angeles`

First we try my own default time zone of [`America/Los_Angeles`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Los_Angeles).

#### java.util.Date

```
// java.util.Date class.
java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date ( input );
```

#### java.time

```
// java.time framework (built into Java 8 and later).
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli ( input );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant ( instant , ZoneId.systemDefault () );
```

#### Joda-Time

```
// Joda-Time library, version 2.9.2.
org.joda.time.Instant jodaInstant = new org.joda.time.Instant ( input );
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime ( input );
```

Dump to console.

```
    System.out.println ( "---|  java.util.Date  |-------" );
    System.out.println ( "JVM’s current default time zone: " + TimeZone.getDefault () );
    System.out.println ( "date: " + date );

    System.out.println ( "---|  java.time  |-------" );
    System.out.println ( "Current ZoneId: " + ZoneId.systemDefault () );
    System.out.println ( "instant: " + instant + " | zdt: " + zdt );

    System.out.println ( "---|  Joda-Time  |-------" );
    System.out.println ( "Current DateTimeZone: " + DateTimeZone.getDefault () );
    System.out.println ( "jodaInstant: " + jodaInstant + " | dateTime: " + dateTime );
```

When run.

```
---|  java.util.Date  |-------
JVM’s current default time zone: sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="America/Los_Angeles",offset=-28800000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,transitions=185,lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=America/Los_Angeles,offset=-28800000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,startYear=0,startMode=3,startMonth=2,startDay=8,startDayOfWeek=1,startTime=7200000,startTimeMode=0,endMode=3,endMonth=10,endDay=1,endDayOfWeek=1,endTime=7200000,endTimeMode=0]]
date: Sun Dec 31 10:30:00 PST 1752
---|  java.time  |-------
Current ZoneId: America/Los_Angeles
instant: 1752-12-31T18:30:00Z | zdt: 1752-12-31T10:37:02-07:52:58[America/Los_Angeles]
---|  Joda-Time  |-------
Current DateTimeZone: America/Los_Angeles
jodaInstant: 1752-12-31T18:30:00.000Z | dateTime: 1752-12-31T10:37:02.000-07:52:58
```

### Time Zone `Asia/Kolkata`

Now we add this single line up top, to specify `Asia/Kolkata` as the time zone.

```
TimeZone.setDefault ( TimeZone.getTimeZone ( "Asia/Kolkata" ) );
```

[`Asia/Kolkata`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asia/Kolkata) is the modern [time zone of India](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_India), normally an offset-from-UTC of `+05:30` (five and a half hours ahead of UTC). Yet in this example we see the offset similarly affected by several minutes and a few seconds in both java.time and Joda-Time. Meanwhile the old java.util.Date shows the first moment of the following year 1753.

When run.

```
---|  java.util.Date  |-------
JVM’s current default time zone: sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Asia/Kolkata",offset=19800000,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=6,lastRule=null]
date: Mon Jan 01 00:00:00 IST 1753
---|  java.time  |-------
Current ZoneId: Asia/Kolkata
instant: 1752-12-31T18:30:00Z | zdt: 1753-01-01T00:23:28+05:53:28[Asia/Kolkata]
---|  Joda-Time  |-------
Current DateTimeZone: Asia/Kolkata
jodaInstant: 1752-12-31T18:30:00.000Z | dateTime: 1753-01-01T00:23:28.000+05:53:28
```

Comment: @subhasankar The solution is to not use the date-time classes for ancient historical values. No need to track time to the nanosecond in 1752. Time zone information is unreliable prior to 1970, and largely forgotten before the twentieth century. There is no practical purpose in using `ZonedDateTime` or other such classes in prior centuries. Either just us `LocalDateTime` (lacking any concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC), or just use text or numbers.